# Electronic components identification

Tags: power-electronics, components

In the picture below, I have a power resistor, which is powered either from 12VDC or 24VAC from the rest circuit, as well as another component, which is inserted on the one cable leading to the resistor.

[image]

My questions are:

1. What does each number mean on the power resistor marking?
2. What could the other component be?

Edit: This is a CCTV camera and the power resistor is used to make sure, through heating, that the glass in front of the lens does not become foggy.

Comment: It would be a help to know what the function of the circuit is. Please [edit] into your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "gold" metal clad power resistor is made by: -

```
S.I.R. SOCIETÀ ITALIANA RESISTOR, Via Isonzo 13, 21053 Castellanza (VA), Italy
```

The general data sheet that describes their metal clad products is [**HERE**](https://www.widap.com/wp-content/uploads/FD_592270R03_RHS10_to_RHS250_513_167.pdf) and that particular resistor is 68 Ω 25 watts: -

[image]

The other component looks like a ferrite core of some sort. The "15" might indicate it has an inductance of 15 μH.

Good luck.

Comment: Any information about the difference between RH, RHS and NH power resistor types?

Comment: @NickG your best bet is to go onto the website for SIR and find out yourself - if the website doesn't tell you then contact SIR. If there's something you don't understand about them, link the datasheet.

Answer (score 1):

The resistor is manufactured by SIR, and is of type [RHS25](http://pe.emcopower.de/storage/pub/power/S.I.R/pdf/cat3/FD590800.pdf). This is a 25W aluminium housed wire-wound resistor.

The `68R J` indicates the resistance and tolerance, that is a 68 Ohm resistor with 5% tolerance.

`1999` is a date code of manufacture, with the first two digits most likely being week in year, and the second two being the year itself, so from May 10th 1999 to May 16th 1999.

The second component is most likely an inductor, but it could also be a capacitor. Hard to tell without removing the heat-shrink tubing.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Could you please also explain the difference between rh, rhs and nh resistors?